# Not able to install pymssql on python3.9 docker image

Tags: python, docker, pymssql

I am trying to build a docker image for a flask application, which requires **pymssql** to connect to the sql server. Have specified **pymssql===2.2.5** in the requirements.txt file and trying to build the image.

I have tried `docker build -t <image-name> .`

```
Collecting pymssql==2.2.5
#9 23.25   Downloading pymssql-2.2.5.tar.gz (170 kB)
#9 23.27      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 170.1/170.1 KB 9.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 23.38   Installing build dependencies: started
#9 27.65   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#9 27.65   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#9 27.90   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
#9 27.90   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#9 27.90   
#9 27.90   × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
#9 27.90   │ exit code: 1
#9 27.90   ╰─> [6 lines of output]
#9 27.90       setup.py: platform.system() => Linux
#9 27.90       setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', '')
#9 27.90       setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.31')
#9 27.90       setup.py: include_dirs => []
#9 27.90       setup.py: library_dirs => []
#9 27.90       setup.py: could not locate 'clock_gettime' function required by FreeTDS.
#9 27.90       [end of output]
#9 27.90   
#9 27.90   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#9 27.90 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because I simply can't reproduce your problem: if I start a container from `python:3.9`  and then `pip install pymssql==2.2.5`, it Just Works without any errors.

Comment: NOOOOO, what was the solution to the original problem? thanks

Answer (score 2):

On Debian, you need install freetds-dev g++

```
apt-get install freetds-dev g++
```